# Function plotting using mesh and meshgrid in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I have to represent this function: c = y * sin(x) using mesh. Where:

```
x = -10:10
y = 0:3:30
```

My code looks like this:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
C = Y*sin(X)';
mesh(X,Y,C);
```

But when I run it I get the following error:

> "Error using mesh (line 71) Data dimensions must agree.".

How do I fix this? I'm not sure how to plot a function where the variables are multiplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a MATLAB licence to test it. But I guess the problem is that you are using the `*` operator, which does a matrix matrix multiplication. You need to do an element-wise multiplication using `.*`, and remove the transpose.

```
C = Y.*sin(X);
```